# ¿Porque la hora en mi base de datos esta 1 hora adelantada?

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo un problema con la hora en mi base de datos, a esta la configure con la zona horaria de Lima, Peru; sino me equivoco es UTC-5, pero al momento de almacenar la fecha en la bd, esta lo guarda una hora adelantada a la hora actual.

Asi es como se muestra en mi base de datos:

```
2024-03-26 11:01:33
```

Y asi es como deberia estar:

```
2024-03-26 10:01:33
```

Esta fecha la guardo en el campo "fecha_hora" de mi tabla y es de tipo "datetime"

Cabe mencionar que la fecha es creada desde la base de datos y no desde el codigo de mi aplicacion, es buena idea hacer esto? es mejor crear la fecha desde el codigo y luego almacenarla en la base de datos? estoy pensando en esto ya que de esa manera puedo evitarme conflictos con la base de datos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si guarda esa fecha, es porque esta en esa fecha... lo otro, es totalmente opiniones y vas a tener de los dos bandos, asi que no vale ninguna respuesta...

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices pero yo modifique la base de datos en la zona horaria de lima y ésta deberia estar a la par de la hora de mi telefono ya que estoy viviendo en lima, pero esta una hora adelantada, lo cual esta mal.

Comment: En tu lugar, probaría `SELECT @@global.time_zone;` o `SELECT @@session.time_zone;` para comprobar si el establecimiento de la zona horaria se hizo correctamente, o qué tiene configurado la base de datos. Y, en función de eso, investigar qué puede estar pasando.

Comment: la base de datos no es la pc donde esta parada.. verificaste la hora del servidor?

Comment: He verificado la hora en mi servidor y esta en UTC-4, no puedo cambiar la hora del servidor ya que es de un cliente. He intentado cambiar la zona horaria de mi base de datos pero no funciona, se sigue manteniendo con SYSTEM.

Comment: Entonces ya encontraste tu problema.. no hay mas que hacer... cambiar la hora en tu codigo es un problema por todos lados. Si el servidor esta en tu pais, y la hora esta mal, pues hay que cambiarla.. si no, hay que trabajar de otra forma, trayendo la hora universal y luego pasandola a la hora que queres...